# Why are my getters not called when I'm trying to access a field from outside the class?

Tags: properties, haxe

I'm getting to know Haxe, and I'm primarily using it to generate Python code and C# DLLs.

However I've run into the same issue multiple times: whenever I try to write getters, they work fine when I access the relevant property from inside a method, but when I try to access them from outside the class they're not even called. I'm starting to suspect I'm missing something fundamental.

For instance if I write the following class:

```
@:expose
@:keep
class TestClass
{
    public var testField(get, null):String;

    private function get_testField():String
    {
        trace("executing getter");
        return "testString";
    }

    public function new() {}

    public function testMethod()
    {
        trace(testField);
    }
}
```

and then in Python:

```py
testInstance = MyModule.TestClass();
testInstance.testMethod();
```

...outputs as expected:

```
executing getter
testString
```

but

```py
print(testInstance.testField)
```

...outputs `None`.

I'm expecting `testInstance.testField` to return `"testString"` in all cases, what am I doing wrong? This is happening in C# as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [properties in Haxe are a *compile-time feature*](https://haxe.org/manual/class-field-property-type-system-impact.html) and don't generate native properties. Not all targets even have properties, and those that do likely don't 100% match Haxe's semantics.

Instead, property access is replaced by calls to the accessor methods (`get_field()`, `set_field()`) at compile time. Consequently,

```haxe
trace(testField);
```

turns into the following when compiled to Python:

```python
print(str(self.get_testField()))
```

So to get consistent results, you'd have to call `get_testField()` on the Python side as well.

For the C# and Flash targets, there is metadata to generate native properties (see `haxe --help-metas`):

> `@:property` - Marks a property field to be compiled as a native C# property (cs only)
>
> `@:getter` - (Class field name) Generates a native getter function on the given field (flash only)
>
> `@:setter` - (Class field name) Generates a native setter function on the given field (flash only)

Note that the C# target's `@:property` only works for properties without a [physical field](https://haxe.org/manual/class-field-property-rules.html#define:-physical-field). In your example, `(get, null)` would have to be replaced with `(get, never)` for it to work.

There is currently an [open feature request](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/5104) for supporting native properties on the JS target via `@:property` as well. This might also make sense for Python, considering it too has native properties. Perhaps consider opening an issue. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, this makes perfect sense!